# .NET Core views using Razor- Multiple same routes

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating a .NET Core API to read/write/update/delete information from a database. I have the bones set up, and now I'm trying to get views incorporated to make things look better. I used Visual Studio's 2017 scaffolding capabilities to set up some basic views. Right now, the index.cshtml view works, it displays information from each row of the database along with an option to edit, view details, or delete each row. That is added through the following 3 lines, which gets put in `<td>` tags within a `foreach` statement to loop through the results for the database (`item` is what each row in the result set from the database is called)

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.id">Edit</a> |
<a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.id">Details</a> |
<a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.id">Delete</a>
```

The only one that is working for me so far is the details link, which uses a function in my controller class and brings me to a view of only that one specific row. I've noticed that the edit and details hrefs are not grabbing the ID of the row, and as a result those links just take me back to the index page that I'm already on. By hovering on each link, here's what I can see each href is set to-

**Edit:** localhost:port/api/results

**Details:** localhost:port/api/results/1 *(this is what the other two should look something like, I believe)*

**Delete:** localhost:port/api/results

I've done a bit of debugging/investigating already, and here are my questions:

1. Can multiple routes have the same URI if they do different things? For example, the details link is a HttpGet, whereas the delete would be a HttpDelete. Can they both have the same URI if they're using different HTTP methods?
2. Does there have to be a controller that does something with the given route before Razor will correctly put together the route?
3. Anything I missed that could be a reason why the ID isn't being added to the hyperlink? All 3 of the edit/details/delete routes are set up exactly the same, yet the ID only gets added to the route for details and not edit or delete.

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes, it's a normal case. You can have */results/1*, *PUT results/1*, *DELETE results/1*, *POST results/1*

2,3)
By design, a link can send request only to GET Method as GET basically is used for retrieving data. However, POST, PUT, DELETE are not intended to be idempotent methods and they usually modify the state of an entity on the server. 
If you want to call POST and DELETE method you should use `<form>`

To solve the issue you have to:

- Create "Edit" and "Delete" GET methods returning a web page with
  required data. For "Edit" - page should consist with `<form>` and several inputs to modify your input. "Delete" usually requires only
  `<form>` with hidden input (id).
- After you finished with WebPages you can use your method through the
  `<form>`

Take a look at this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-2.0).

Comment: So if I am allowed to have multiple hrefs built the same as long as they do different things, any idea why the edit and delete links aren't getting the IDs appended to the route?

Comment: @Hollywood, added answer how to fix your problem. Shortly - Only get methods can be used in href. By design, link can only be used for retrieving information.

Comment: That makes sense and explains part of my issues. One additional question, how can I tell which HTTP method my API to use if the edit, details, and delete URIs are all "results/{id}"? I implemented the delete as shown in the tutorial you linked, but now the delete link just brings me to my details page. I'm guessing the root of that issue that both links have the same href

Comment: @Hollywood to tell witch HTTP Method to use you can apply several ways: in <form> set attribute method to POST or GET (other methods don't work in form). To send Delete or PUT you should use js, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Also for delete you can create other POST (with another url) method, which deletes an entity and after send you back to Index page.